# String.Substring error in android

Tags: java

```
   char[] string1 = null;
   string1 = orignalstring.substring(10, 5).toCharArray();
```

I am using this code on my android application. The `original string` is 80 character in length. Still i keep getting this error.

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} 
to activity {com.example.AppExample1/com.example.AppExample1.MainActivity}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=80; regionStart=10; regionLength=-5
```

Please help

Comment: Try this way string1 = orignalstring.substring(5,10).toCharArray();

Comment: Please read the doc of substring.

Comment: `substring` takes `from` and `to`, not `from` and `length`. You can't go from ten to five.

Comment: [#subString(int start,int end)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way `string1 = orignalstring.substring(10,15).toCharArray();`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax of `substring` method:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
```

or

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

Update: if you want 5 characters from the 10th you can use,

```
orignalstring.substring(10, 15).toCharArray();
```

like this.

So use this method properly.